# Google Sheet API access with Application Default credentials

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-oauth, scopes

I am trying to access Google Sheet (read only mode) from Python (runs in GKE).

I am able to get application default creds, but getting scopes issue (as I am missing `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly` scope). See code below:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client import client

creds=client.GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId='XXXXXXXXXX', range='Sheet1!A:C').execute()
```

The output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 840, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/XXXXXX/values/Sheet1%21A%3AC?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
```

I tried to read any documentation available, but al of the relevant scope related is using external service account JSON file.

Is there a way to use Application Default and add the required scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to define your scopes in the `create_scoped()` method of `GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()`.*

#### Code snippet:

```py
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default().create_scoped(
          ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'])
```

#### References:

- [`oauth2client.client` module - oauth2client 4.1.2 documentation](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.client.html#oauth2client.client.GoogleCredentials.create_scoped)
- [Source code for `oauth2client.client` - `GoogleCredentials.create_scoped`](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/oauth2client/client.html#GoogleCredentials.create_scoped)

Comment: I substituted your snippet for OP's `creds=` line but I get this error as of July 14 2022:

`HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/values/Class%20Data%21A2%3AE....?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">`

Comment: This appears to only work when the default credentials are service account credentials. In particular, it does not work if you run `gcloud auth application-default login` with your user credentials and then try to run this code snippet.

Comment: My comment is wrong, please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 5):

This answer collects the great information from the other answers into one place, but also describes how to properly use `gcloud auth application-default login`.

---

Regardless of the particular library or particular programming language, you need credentials that permit you to access the Google Sheets API. Within Google, there are two kinds of credentials:

1. Human user accounts.
2. Service accounts.

Google's libraries automatically look for credentials in a few places:

1. The `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_DEFAULT` environment variable.
2. The gcloud credentials config. At time of writing this is `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json` (if `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is unset, I think it uses `~/.config`).
3. The latent credentials of the GCE VM as provided by the ["metadata server"](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview)

---

The service account credentials have no notion of "scopes". Another way of understanding this is that service account credentials implicitly have every scope.

The human application-default credentials must be explicitly constructed with the Sheets API OAuth2 "scope" otherwise they are not permitted to use the Sheets API. In particular, the error:

```
Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

indicates your credentials do no have a Sheets API scope.

---

In summary, there are two ways to access the Sheets API.

1. Use a service account credential and this code:

```
from google import auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly',
]
credentials, project_id = auth.default(scopes=scopes)  # Returns a tuple.
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
service.spreadsheets().values().get(
    spreadsheetId='1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms',
    range='Class Data!A:F'
).execute()['values']
```

2. Use a human application-default credential with the scopes configured properly.

In your shell:

```bash
gcloud auth application-default login \
            --scopes=openid,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project YOUR_GCP_PROJECT
```

Now you can run the same code as in case (1).

Answer (score 0):

The library `oauth2client` is now deprecated. Use this library `google-auth` instead.
The user guide is here:
https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/user-guide.html

So this code:

```py
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly',
]
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default().create_scoped(scopes)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
```

Should be replaced with this code:

```py
from google import auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly',
]
credentials, project_id = auth.default(scopes=scopes)  # Returns a tuple.
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
```

Also, another library `google-auth-httplib2` might be needed for the library `google-auth` to work properly based on this reply:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/issues/190#issuecomment-322837328

Comment: Did this actually work for you in 2021? I can't get this to work as of July 14 2022. I took exactly your second block and added:

`service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId='1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms', range='Class Data!A2:E''....').execute()`


But I get this error:


`HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/values/Class%20Data%21A2%3AE....?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">`

Comment: This appears to only work when the default credentials are service account credentials. In particular, it does not work if you run `gcloud auth application-default login` with your user credentials and then try to run this code snippet.

Comment: My comment is slightly incorrect, if you want to use application-default credentials you must specify a scope that includes spreadsheet access. The command to do that is present at this other SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72986975/6823256

Answer (score 0):

When running on GCP Compute Engine, I found this to be necessary:

1. Retrieve the current access scopes (also can be found [in the Docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts) under 'Default scopes'):

```
gcloud compute instances describe INSTANCE_NAME --zone=ZONE --format="value(serviceAccounts[].scopes[])"
```

2. Ensure the instance is stopped.
3. Set the updated access scopes, including the new scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly` (or whatever other scopes you need). You specify these as a comma-separated string.

```
gcloud compute instances set-service-account INSTANCE_NAME --zone=ZONE --service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL --scopes=CURRENT_SCOPES,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly
```

---

You will also need to share your Spreadsheet with the Service Account, like if you shared it with another user, otherwise you'll get `403 The caller does not have permission`:

[image: sharing_spreadsheet_with_service_account]

---

Then in code:

```py
import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']
credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=scopes)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
```

You can verify the currently used Service Account by calling:

```py
import google.auth.transport.requests

request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(request=request)
print(f'Using GCP credentials: {credentials.service_account_email}')
```

---

*Context:*

*Fixing this is particularly annoying, as upon using a user-defined Service Account, the Compute Engine Instance's console tells us:*

```
Access scopes 
Use IAM roles with service accounts to control VM access.
```

*However, as of writing this there is no 'Spreadsheets Reader' role, or similar. Likewise, no relevant permission come up when trying to create a Role including permissions with keywords 'drive' or 'spreadsheets'. If I'm missing a Role that covers these permissions, please let me know. Otherwise, I'd imagine that once such Roles are added, using these would be the expected way of fixing this 403 issue.*