# Google Sheet API access with Application Default credentials using scopes giving Insufficient Scopes error while running on GCP VM

Tags: python, google-sheets

I am trying to access Google Sheet (read write mode) from Python (runs in GKE). I have tried both outh2client as well as google-auth approach but it gives the same error every time:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1kvHv1OBCzr9GnFxRu9RTJC7jjQjc9M4rAiDnhyak2Sg/values/vm_metrics%21A10?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'method': 'google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.GetValues', 'service': 'sheets.googleapis.com'}}]">
```

This is my code using outh2client:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client import client

creds=client.GoogleCredentials.get_application_default().create_scoped(
          ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'])
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId='whatev', range='Sheet1!A:C').execute()
```

This is my code using google-auth:

```
import google.auth

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

creds, project=google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId='XXXXXXXXXX', range='Sheet1!A:C').execute()
```

Answer (score 5):

AFAICT, this is the same question as [Google Sheet API access with Application Default credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61412481/google-sheet-api-access-with-application-default-credentials). The solution (from that SO post) is

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client import client

creds = client.GoogleCredentials.get_application_default().create_scoped(
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']
)
response = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
    spreadsheetId='XXXXXXXXXX',
    range='Sheet1!A:C'
).execute()
rows = response['values']
```

*However*, this *will not work* with the usual application default credentials you get from `gcloud auth application-default login`. You'll get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-2-2a9ba7e9e38f>", line 8, in <module>
    sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId='1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms', range='Class Data!A2:E''....').execute()
  File "/Users/dking/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/dking/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 855, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/values/Class%20Data%21A2%3AE....?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
```

The fix is actually quite simple! h/t to [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2247123/james) for pointing this out in a comment. You must expand the OAuth scopes for your application default credentials to include the Google Sheets API and you must also set a quota project which Google Sheets uses for rate limiting. At time of writing there is no [documented cost](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) to using the Sheets API, but there is a 300 requests per project per minute limit.

```bash
gcloud auth application-default login \
            --scopes=openid,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project YOUR_GCP_PROJECT
```

Comment: What a sad ending for my 3 hours research and debugging.

Comment: It is possible to add the spreadsheet scope to application default credentials when they are initially created:

`gcloud auth application-default login --scopes=openid,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
`
Note that the auth/cloud-platform scope and other basic scopes are also still there.

In addition to adding the scope, since sheets is billed by client, you need to set a quota project for the credentials: `gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project QUOTA_PROJECT`