# How to read a spreadsheet using python API and Applications Default Credentials?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, scope, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I have the following code:

```
    scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']

    credentials, project = google.auth.default(scopes=scope)

    service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result_input = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=id,range=range).execute()
```

But I'm getting a 403, even when the sheet is public:
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<SHEET_ID_HERE>/values/<RANGE_HERE>?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'service': 'sheets.googleapis.com', 'method': 'google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.GetValues'}}]">
```

I have

- Google SDK well configured
- I am the owner of the GCP project
- I am the owner of the google sheet with the same email (that know is public)

I didn't want to download any .json api key. Do I have another option? what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
It seems to be impossible to use ADC to access the google sheet api. It MUST be by service account or Oauth2 configuration

here's a reference to another similar question
[Google Sheet API access with Application Default credentials using scopes giving Insufficient Scopes error while running on GCP VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72526314/google-sheet-api-access-with-application-default-credentials-using-scopes-giving)

Very sad ending for my search

Comment: You need to provide the key somehow. Why not download the JSON?

Comment: I'm trying to generate the credentials direct from my application environment. The same way when I instantiate a big query or storage client. The aplication should falls back to the default inferred from the environment

Comment: Do you use your own user account credential as default credential? Did you authenticate yourself with`gcloud auth application-default login`?

Comment: Yes, but for  outside google api services, we need a service account/oauth